# Jenkins slave (agent) on Windows sometimes fails with timeout on socketAccept when started

Tags: windows, jenkins, slave

I set up Jenkins slave agent to run as service on Windows server but it works sporadically.

```
Starting javaw.exe -Xrs  -jar "d:\build_tools\jenkins\slave.jar" -tcp d:\build_tools\jenkins\port.txt
```

Sometimes it starts and sometimes it fails with the following error. I can't figure out why.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.Launcher.runAsTcpServer(Launcher.java:312)
at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:211)
at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:173)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be caused by many problems, but most common are those:

- Firewall or Antivirus are blocking communications:
  disable them and see if it helps
- When the slave starts, the network is not available yet:
  make sure the service is set to retry after a minute or two

See also Jenkins' guides:

- [Step by step guide to set up master and agent machines on Windows](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows)
- [How to troubleshoot JNLP slaves connection issues with Jenkins](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218097237-How-to-troubleshoot-JNLP-slaves-connection-issues-with-Jenkins-)